# Creating a Div that pops and then disppear in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random

I am trying to write in javascript a code that shows a div in a random place, then blacks it out after 1000ms and waits for a user's click. My problem is in blackening it (the line that start in //). Could you explain me what's wrong in this?

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #test {
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#d2fcd9;
}

  </style>

  <title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
$('#test').click(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),



    });

    //setTimeout(function() {    $div.css({background-color: '#000000'  }); },          300);



});
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">
  <div id="test" style="left: 1168px; top: 222px;"></div>
```

Comment: try double quotes on "background-color" setTimeout(function() {    $div.css({background-color: '#000000'  }); },          300);

Comment: Thanks! This works. But I couldn't change the background color for the next round - after I click the div I want to see it again in the original color.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I've tried it . As I wrote it works just after the first round - if I click the now black div nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a toggle. 
Write $('#test').toggle(); Make sure to target the div id.
This will add on the first click and remove on the second click. Additionally, you can set the time on it to whatever you see fit. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/.

Comment: Thanks! It works.. but I need to toggle the div some time after it appears in the first place - otherwise the div appears first as black then bright (the opposite of what I need). How can I do this?

Comment: You can put a number inside the toggle, in this case toggle (1000):

Comment: It seems that after the dic disappears I can't click on it - it reappears just if I catch it in time.. I want to click on it after its already black.

Comment: do toggleClass and add a class to the div. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/. This will turn on and off the black if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Did you mea this:
    setTimeout(function() {       $('#test').toggleClass( "background-color" );    }, 1000);
This change didn't work for me.

Comment: No, you add a class to the div such as <div class='black'> in which you add your bgc to whatever you want. Then when you do  $('#test').toggleClass( "black" ); }, 1000) it should add the class on the first click and then remove the class on the next click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #test {
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#d2fcd9;
}

  </style>

  <title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
$('#test').click(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),



    });



var color =  $div.css("background-color");
if(color === "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"){
color = "#d2fcd9;"
}else{
color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
}
var timer = setTimeout(function() {    $div.css({"background-color": color  }); 
 clearTimeout(timer);

 },          300);



});
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">
  <div id="test" style="left: 1168px; top: 222px;"></div>
```

use if-else check to toggle color and use double quotes on "background-color" also clear Timout timer in  setTimeout

Comment: Its works just after the first round - if I click the now black div nothing happens.